# problem in getting desired date format in loop

Tags: php, date

I have a date format like this :

```
  $date1 = "Sun May 09 20:07:50 +0000 2010";
```

and I have to convert it to: 09-05-2010

I am echoing it with echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date1));

When I print this individually it gives proper result but I am using it in loop 
  it gives me results like: 31-12-1969

The loop i am using is :

```
foreach($userinfo as $k=>$v)
{
if($k == 'test')
 {
    foreach($v as $k1=>$v1)
    {
      echo $v1."<br>";
      //echo strtotime($v1)."<br>";
      //echo $date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($v1));
    }
 }
}
```

Guys when I echo $v1 it gives me:Sun May 09 20:07:50 +0000 2010
  Also when I echo strtotime($v1); it gives blank.
 However funny thing is I am getting this conversion perfectly in 1D loop.

Can you help, please?

Comment: http://php.net/date - what second parameter must be?

Comment: echo $v1 every time to see it's actual value.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date1)) ;
```

Comment: you have to use strtotime() as the [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function expects a timestamp as its second parameter

I just ran your loop and it works fine, its obviously your input, instead of echoing the date, echo $v1 and give us you're values

Comment: thank you guys for your support, i could solve the problem with your valuable quick help. Thank you again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is `$date1 = "Sun May 09 20:07:50 +0000 2010";` outside the loop? If it is, make sure you only change it with `strtotime` and `date` once.

Comment: It is inside the loop, each user's date should convert into that format.

Comment: thank you guys for your support, i could solve the problem with your valuable quick help. Thank you again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you could simplify by writing :

```
foreach ($userinfo['test'] as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $k1 => $v1) {
        echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($v1));
    }   
}
```

---

The second *strtotime()* argument is not useful for you, it is in case you use the function to make operations on timestamps, like :

```
echo strtotime("-1 day", mktime(...));
```

---

Just do `print_r($userinfo['test'])` to see what's really inside.

Comment: thank you guys for your support, i could solve the problem with your valuable quick help. Thank you again!!!!